# Laravel 4 pass input from blade to controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a project in laravel 4.

In my blade file i have:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
            <a href="{{ action('HomeController@getMore') }}" data-limit="12" data-gap="12">Show more </a>
</div>
```

I want to pass my limit and gap to the controller. In the controller i use Input::get('limit'); but i get back a null. 
Even Input::all() returns null.

Any tips?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
        <a href="{{ action('HomeController@getMore', ['dataLimit'=>12, 'dataGap'=>12]) }}" data-limit="12" data-gap="12">Show more </a>
```

And ensure that your route and controller passed params.
Route must be configured with `dataLimit` and `dataGap` params, and controller method must accept it.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML(VIEW) CODE**

1. Code for `a` tag 

   `<a href="url('submit/Parameters...')">click ok </a>`
2. Form code 

   `<form method="POST" action="{{url('submit/Parameters..')}}" method="post">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   ...
   </form>`

**ROUTE CODE**

3. route code with action

   `Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {
   echo "id is : ".$id ;
   });`
4. route code for controller

   `Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@show');`

   **CONTROLLERS CODE**

   `<?php`

`namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

`use App\User;`

`use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;`

`class ShowProfile extends Controller
{
    public function index($id)
    {
        echo $id;
    }
}`

for more information you see following like 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers
and https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing

Answer (score 1):

Input is for forms. If you want to use anchors, you will have to pass parameters to url like this

```
<a href="/url?limit=12&gap=12" >Show more </a>
```

This makes them optional to your controller. You just need to get them with `request()`.

```
$limit = request('limit');
$gap = request('gap');
```